# getting error when trying to build a phonegap app

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, phonegap-desktop-app

I am trying to build an hybrid app, I was built apps with the same environment about an hour ago but now I am not able to build for any platforms.
The cordova is giving me the below error

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\applications\quadBuild>phonegap build android
[phonegap] executing 'cordova build android'...


D:\xampp\htdocs\applications\quadBuild>cordova build android
Error: Non-whitespace before first tag.
Line: 0
Column: 1
Char:
    at error (C:\Users\Spartan 7\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_m
odules\cordova-lib\node_modules\elementtree\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:347:8)
    at strictFail (C:\Users\Spartan 7\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\n
ode_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\elementtree\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:364
:22)
    at Object.write (C:\Users\Spartan 7\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova
\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\elementtree\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:6
03:11)
    at XMLParser.feed (C:\Users\Spartan 7\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordo
va\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\elementtree\lib\parsers\sax.js:48:15)
    at ElementTree.parse (C:\Users\Spartan 7\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\co
rdova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\elementtree\lib\elementtree.js:263:1
0)
    at Object.exports.XML (C:\Users\Spartan 7\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\c
ordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\elementtree\lib\elementtree.js:593:
13)
    at Object.module.exports.parseElementtreeSync (C:\Users\Spartan 7\AppData\Ro
aming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\util\xml-helpers.js:
123:38)
    at ConfigFile_load [as load] (C:\Users\Spartan 7\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo
dules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\util\ConfigFile.js:69:33)
    at new ConfigFile (C:\Users\Spartan 7\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordo
va\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\util\ConfigFile.js:48:10)
    at ConfigKeeper_get [as get] (C:\Users\Spartan 7\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo
dules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\util\ConfigKeeper.js:51:23)
```

this is happening after a restart. what could be the problem? Please help me.

Comment: have you found a solution? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered removing the Byte Order Mark character which Windows systems automatically prepend to utf-8 files from your XML data?

Before passing the xml value to be parsed try removing that character:

```
var cleanedXML = origXML.replace("\ufeff", "");
```

Source: http://www.multiasking.com/blog/xml2js-sax-js-non-whitespace-before-first-tag/